# In Dockerfile, COPY all contents of current directory except one directory

Tags: docker, dockerfile

In my Dockerfile, I have the following:

```
COPY . /var/task
```

...which copies my app code into the image.

**I need to exclude the `vendor/` directory when performing this copy.**

- I cannot add `vendor/` to `.dockerignore`, because that directory needs to be part of the image when it gets built within the image with a `RUN composer install`.
- I cannot specify every file and directory that *should* be copied, because they may change and I can't rely on other developers to keep the list updated.

I've tried the following, with the following errors:

```
COPY [^vendor$]* /var/task
```

> When using COPY with more than one source file, the destination must be a directory and end with a /

```
COPY [^vendor$]*/ /var/task
```

> COPY failed: no source files were specified

Comment: I believe that the first error you had was related with `/var/task` since that is your destination. Did you try `COPY [^vendor$]* /var/task/`?

Comment: I am confused by "I cannot add `vendor/` to `.dockerignore`...". If you're excluding the directory from `COPY`, as you're asking here, it's not going to be available within the image so it doesn't matter whether or not it's listed in the `.dockerignore` file.

Comment: `.dockerignore` only affects whether `COPY` can see a given directory; it won't prevent that directory from being in the final image.

Comment: @NPinheiro That command worked without error (I misread the initial warning, adding / to the src, not dest). But the copy resulted in a strange result, with contents of subdirectories ending up in the top-level directory, and overwrites where subdirectories and files has matching names.

Comment: @larsks vendor is created within the image using RUN before the app code is copied in from the host. This is to make sure that, if the app code already has a vendor directory, it won't overwrite the one created in the image (which is happening when I use an existing workspace on Jenkins)

Comment: @DavidMaze Thank you! You're right. This was the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually enough to add the `vendor` directory to the `.dockerignore` file.

You can broadly follow the flow of files through `docker build` in three phases:

1. `docker build` reads files from the directory you name, ignoring things in the `.dockerignore` file, and sends them to the Docker daemon as the *build context*.
2. The `COPY` instruction copies files from the build context into the container filesystem.
3. `RUN` instructions do further transformation or processing.

If you put `vendor` in the `.dockerignore` file, it prevents the directory from being included in the build context.  The build will go somewhat faster, and `COPY` won't have the files to copy into the image.  It won't prevent a `RUN composer install` step later on from creating its own `vendor` directory in the image.

Comment: (How) can I add a new .dockerfile halfway through the build, with or without a multistage dockerfile?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is an easy solution to this problem.

If you need `vendor` for `RUN composer install` and you're not using a multistage build then it doesn't matter if you remove the `vendor` folder in the copy command. If you've copied it into the build earlier then it's going to be present in your final image, even if you don't copy it over in your `COPY` step.

One way to get around this is with multi-stage builds, like so:

```
FROM debian as base
COPY . /var/task/
RUN rm -rf /var/task/vendor
FROM debian
COPY --from=base /var/task /var/task
```

If you can use this pattern in your larger build file then the final image will contain all the files in your working directory except `vendor`.

There's still a performance hit though. You're still going to have to copy the entire `vendor` directory into the build, and depending on what docker features you're using that will still take a long time. But if you need it for `composer install` then there's really no way around this.